# Each of the following functions f is bijective. Describe its inverse.

Tags: functions, inverse

QA,B: Each of the following functions f is bijective. Describe its inverse.

A:
$$f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow (0,\infty); \text{ defined by } f(x)=e^x $$

For this function, I said the inverse is:
$$f^{-1}:(0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}; \text{ defined by } f^{-1}(x)=\ln(x) $$

B:

$$f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}; \text{ defined by } f(x)=x^3+1 $$

At first, for the inverse, I said:

$$f^{-1}:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}; \text{ defined by } f^{-1}(x)=\sqrt[3]{x-1}$$

but then I notice if x=-1 then the value inside the root will be negative which is illegal, therefore I adjusted by domain and codomain and obtained:

$$f^{-1}:\mathbb{R^{\geq 1}} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^{\geq 0}}; \text{ defined by } f^{-1}(x)=\sqrt[3]{x-1}$$

Can anyone verify if these answers are correct?

Comment: The cubic root applies to all real numbers.

Comment: Cubic roots (as well as $n$-th roots when $n$ is odd) are well defined in all of $\mathbb{R}$, as Frank said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are fine except you should not adjust the domain in the second example.  It is perfectly fine to have a negative inside a cube root. For example, $\sqrt[3]{-64}=-4$.

Comment: Oh wow, my head has been so wrapped around square roots that I applied the rules to cubic roots. Didn't realize the mistake. thanks!